# JUnit RunListener doesn't work when I want to call it from ANT

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have a custom JUnit runner with listener `RunListener`. In eclipse environment this `testRunFinished(Result result)` listener works as expected, but when I run it through ANT this listener is not initialized. Added in build.xml special annotation `enableTestListenerEvents="true"` but this did help.

Here is my runner's piece of the code:

```
        @Override
        public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
               notifier.addListener(new RunListener(){
                   @Override public void testRunFinished(Result result) throws Exception {
                     super.testRunFinished(result);
                   }
                 }
               );
        }
```

and build.xml:

```
<junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" fork="yes" enableTestListenerEvents="true">
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Btw, `@Override public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {..}` works fine, seems only `testRunFinished` is not working properly.
Same bug, as I understood it hasn't been fixed yet: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54970
My ANT version is 1.9.4, tried also 1.8.4.

Comment: are the tests within main.test.java directory?

Comment: tests runs normally, they are in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

are the tests within main.test.java directory?
if yes then
it might be a problem of build.xml configuration, see
[exemple](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/running-tests-with-ant.html)

You might need to specify the test classes

```
 <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${reports.tests}">
    <fileset dir="${src.test}">
      <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </batchtest>
```

Comment: As I said before, test classes are specified and tests runs as expected.